# convert firebase server timestamps in Unix epoch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unix-timestamp

I am reading my user last login time like this in my html:

```
<tr>
<td>Last Logged In</td>
<td>{{user.lastlogin}}</td>
</tr>
```

it is displaying a number like this: `1477524135105`

and when I save the info to the database, I do like this:

```
DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).update({
lastlogin: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

how can I show the date and time in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add the date format you want:

```
<td>{{user.lastlogin | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
```